# Multiple equilibria for zero sum game?

Tags: game-theory

Is there any example of a zero-sum game with multiple equilibria?

Answer (score 6):

This one has infinitely many:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&A&B\\\hline
A&0,0&0,0\\\hline
B&0,0&0,0\\\hline
\end{array}

A less trivial example (again with a continuum of NEs, h/t M.Greinecker):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&A&B&C&D\\\hline
A&1,-1&-1,1&0,0&0,0\\\hline
B&-1,1&1,-1&0,0&0,0\\\hline
C&0,0&0,0&1,-1&-1,1\\\hline
D&0,0&0,0&-1,1&1,-1\\\hline
\end{array}

Comment: There should be more than four equilibria. Note that the set of strategies of a player guaranteeing the minmax and the set of strategies of the other player guaranteeing the maxmin are both closed under mixtures. By the Minimax theorem, both players playing such a mixture will result in a Nash equilibrium. So there should be a continuum of Nash equilibria.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks. You're right indeed.